# How to use thunder storm?

Tags: magicka

I've found the Thunder Storm spell combination

> In a cave in chapter 8 (or 9)

Based on how well it was hidden, I thought it should be a very powerful spell, and it is. It calls rain and lots of lightning strikes! The problem is every time I cast the spell I end up killing my self twice and killing no enemies! I'm wondering if there is a trick to using this spell? I've already tried shield it didn't help that much :(

**Edit**

Using the best lighting shield I could conjure `AAAAE`, I kept myself alive! But out of maybe 20 lighting strikes none hit enemies and maybe around 10 hit me (without damaging me  due to the shield).

Does it always act in this way? Or should I do something to make it hit my enemies?

Comment: Maybe you have to wait till the first lightning and stand on that spot. I mean lightning never strikes on the same spot twice.

Answer (score 5):

Casting shield + water + frost + lightning will give you a personal shield that will protect you from melee and lightning damage. Use that instead of a shield aura to prevent enemies piggybacking on your lightning immunity. Keep in mind that a single thunderbolt will strip you of this shield, and you will need to cast an aura of water immunity to protect yourself from getting shocked due to being wet while re-casting the spell.

There is no reliable way to make thunderstorm hit the enemies more often than it normally would. Thunderbolts will randomly strike within 25 yards of the caster's location, biased towards the 20 yard mark and will hit elevated points more often.

Alternatively, wear the Tron robe that gives you lightning absorbtion for full healing whenever you are struck by a lightning bolt. Warning: prolonged exposure to the Tron robe may cause cheesiness.

Comment: there is a problem with your new answer too, your suggestion will result in damage based shield opposed to the time base shield AAAAE is. it means the shield break after 4rd time lighting hits me, and I die at least once during the storm!

Comment: Obviously. Thunderstorm is a dangerous magick.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48993/how-to-protect-yourself-from-exploding-electric-ice-wall)

[QFAER] Water, Lightning | Prevents Wet (Very useful in Thunderstorm)

you might want to add additional lightning resistance [QFAAER] for increased durability

Comment: You can't use water and lightning in the same spell.

Comment: @kotekzot well it is not water, but steam and frost, which allows you to do exactly what you can't QF [Steam], can be used with A [Lightning] and E [Shield] and R [Frost]

Answer (score -2):

Here is a video showing how to find and use it: http://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=3JyL1aJw9kA&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D3JyL1aJw9kA